# Signal end of file in serial communication

Tags: linux, terminal

What control character do I need to send to make the serial client receive end of file or end of stream result? Is there such a thing? For example if I simply cat a serial device into a file, is it somehow possible to make the cat program receive end of file when a certain character is sent so that it exists? Some kind of stty setting perhaps?

(I'm not even sure how to word this question) Basically I want to define a character that when sent by the sending device will make the read call in the receiving device return end of file. I suppose it must be a terminal setting as opposed to being a feature of the terminal program.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title of your question. This is indicated by selecting the checkmark next to the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was to disable raw mode on the terminal explicitly and then send \x04 character (end of transmission) from the sending uart to signal that the stream is over.

```
stty -F <device> -raw <baud> 
cat <device>
```

"cat" will exit when sending side sends 0x04 value which is handled internally by serial driver instead of being passed to the program when terminal is not in raw mode.

Comment: this does not seem to work for me. i can see the `\x04` bytes transmitted when using picocom (with its `--imap spchex` feature) and after using `stty` `hd` does not show them either (thus I presume they are handled somewhere, in cooked mode, i.e. with `stty raw`, they show up in `hd`). However, cat does not exit.

Comment: It's important to note that the `\x04` character has to be followed by a newline to register correctly. ;)